# Inside div 100% height of link

Tags: html, css

I know when using `100% height` the elements parents must have `100% height`.

I want to make `.overlay` `height: 100%;` but I can't get it to work.

If I change `.col` to `height: 100%` it works but I don't want `.col` to be 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/8HfjV/

Is there anyway around this? I noticed if I give an `a` tag `display:block` and `height: 100%;` that works. So is there a way to do it for a DIV?

HTML:

```
<div class="col col1">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay"></div>            
        <img src="#">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.col {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    Position: relative;
}

.col a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.col img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.col1 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the class name is `overlay` I believe you want it to overlap the `img`?

If so use `position: absolute;`. Your div is set to `height: 100%;` but its `width` is `0` so change it to `100%` as well.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HfjV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to the `<a />` and `position: absolute; width:100%;height:100%` to the `.overly`

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HfjV/5/)

Comment: Anchors cannot self-close (just nitpicking here :).